# Can't use Mono.Cairo

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, cairo

I'm trying to develop a simple test application with MonoDevelop (On ubuntu).

I've tried adding reference to Mono.Cairo, but I can't access the namespace Mono.Cairo within the IDE.

What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you installed the library? `sudo apt-get install libmono-cairo2.0-cil` or something similar? I'm not sure if that dependency is found automatically by MonoDevelop, perhaps you also need to specify the dependency even when installed.

Comment: Thank you :). I'll try when the Ubuntu-Machine will be free.

Comment: Terminal output:
"Unable to locate package libmono-cairo2.0-cli
Couldn't find any package by regex libmono-cairo2.0-cli"

Comment: look at this page: http://www.mono-project.com/Mono_Basics, under the Gtk section, you can see how mono libraries are added to your search path in order to be found, i guess your problem is quite similar. i'm far from an expert on mono, i.e. take these avdvice with a grain of salt...

Comment: @GiladNaaman your problem might be related to the name being spelled wrong in this answer. I think the file ends in "cil" and people commonly mistype it since "cli" is used in programming frequently. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It might just be that Monodevelop hasn't loaded the code-completion properly yet.  Try calling a cairo method and see if it builds.

It is sometimes helpful to run MD in a terminal window as it can often print useful debug/warnings there.

Comment: I'm new to linux. What is the MD command? Couldn't find it on google.

Comment: :| I feel so stupid. I'm used to windows where you can cd to the folder of the exe and run it. How can I do that with linux?

Comment: this actually works the same way as windows, a program must be in a folder in the PATH environment variable.  Windows PATH additionally contains "." which means  'current folder'.  To run .net things you just type "mono thing.exe"  in the folder with the exe and all the dlls